# What is the probability of finding a sorted sequence of length $L$ in an array of $N$ randomly generated numbers?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

Numbers are generated from a uniform distribution.

I started working on this problem but I have hit a wall.

I have figured out that if I have a set of $k$ integers $S=\{0,1,2,...k−1\}$ , and that if I randomly draw $L$ numbers from that set to make a list of size $L$, the probability of that list being sorted is $\frac{1}{k^L}\binom{L+k-1}{L}$.

Now, If I am not wrong, I have to count the number ways/times of such a sequence can occur in an array of size $N$ (and then multiply with the above probability to get the final expression), but I am not sure how to do that. I have completely blocked out.

Can someone help me solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with your analysis.  First of all, assuming that you are given $k$ distinct numbers, and you chose all $k$ numbers, one at a time, without replacement, then the probability that the numbers that you chose are in strictly ascending order is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{k!}.$  This is because there are $(k!)$ ways that the selection of numbers may be ordered, only one of which is in strictly ascending order.

I am assuming that all $k$ numbers are distinct.

Then, if you instead draw a subset of $L$ numbers, there are (similarly) $L!$ ways that these numbers might be drawn, only one of which is in strictly ascending order.

Therefore, the probability that the $L$ (**distinct**) numbers are drawn (**without replacement**) in strictly ascending order is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{L!}.$

---

Assuming that (so far) I have interpreted the specific problem as you intend, then it seems as if the question being posed is:

Suppose that $L \leq N \leq k$, where there are $k$ total distinct numbers, of which $N$ numbers will be drawn without replacement.  What is the probability that there will be a subsequence of at least $L$ consecutive numbers, within the sequence of $N$ numbers, such that the L consecutive numbers are in strictly ascending order.

---

**If** this is the problem to be attacked, then one approach is [Inclusion-Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

That is, for $1 \leq i \leq (N - L + 1)$, let $A_i$ denote the set of all possible sequences of the $N$ numbers such that the subsequence that starts at position $i$, and lasts for $L$ positions is in strictly ascending order.

Given a set $S$ with a finite number of elements, let $|S|$ denote the number of elements in $S$.

Then, the final computation will be $$\frac{|A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \cdots \cup A_{(N-L+1)}|}{N!}. \tag1 $$

---

**Edit**
In the above computation, I took the shortcut that it is irrelevant how many elements $k$ are in the superset.  Once the $N$ (distinct) items are drawn, without replacement, the problem is totally encapsulated by a consideration of the $(N!)$ ways that these $N$ items may be ordered.

---

The computation of the numerator in (1) above is standard:

Let $T_1 = |A_1| + |A_2| + \cdots + |A_{(N-L+1)}|.$

Let $\displaystyle T_2 = \sum_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 \leq (N-L+1)} |A_{i_1} \cap A_{i_2}|.$

That is, $T_2$ represents the sum of $\binom{N - L + 1}{2}$ terms.

Similarly, for $3 \leq r \leq (N-L+1)$,

let $\displaystyle T_r = \sum_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_r \leq (N - L + 1)} ~|A_{i_1} \cap A_{i_2} \cap \cdots \cap A_{i_r}|.$

That is, $T_r$ represents the sum of $\binom{N - L + 1}{r}$ terms.

Then, the numerator in (1) above equals

$$\sum_{a = 1}^{(N-L+1)} (-1)^{a-1}T_a.$$

---

Then, it becomes a simple matter of trying for elegant shortcuts.

For example, $A_1$ leaves $(N-L)$ elements unordered, and so $|A_1| = \binom{N}{L} \times (N-L)!.$  That is, there are $\binom{N}{L}$ choices for the first $L$ items in $A_1$, these first $L$ items can only be ordered in $1$ way, and the other $N-L$ items can be ordered in any way.

By symmetry, you have that $|A_1| = |A_2| = \cdots = |A_{(N-L+1)}|.$

Therefore, $T_1 = (N-L+1) \times |A_1|$.

While the computation of $T_2$ admits some shortcuts, it is nowhere as easy as the computation of $T_1$.  That is, when computing $|A_{i_1} \cap A_{i_2}| ~: ~(i_1 < i_2)$ you have to be concerned about two things:

- Is there an intersection?  That is, is $(i_1) + (L-1) \geq  i_2$.
- If so, what is the length of the intersection.  That is, how much is $(i_1) + (L) - (i_2).$

Unfortunately, these considerations snowball, when similarly attacking the computations of $T_3, T_4, \cdots.$

---

Generally, besides Inclusion-Exclusion, the two other approaches to this problem that I am familiar with are the direct approach, and recursion.  Clearly, Inclusion-Exclusion is no walk in the park.  I do think that it is better than the direct approach.

That means that recursion is sort of a wild card, that may yield easier analysis.

Comment: Thank you for your anwswer! The problem didn't specify if $L \leq N \leq k$ , that is, only $L \leq N$ if that makes any difference. I don't have almost any experience with combinatorics, so I'm sorry if anything I write sounds dumb.  Considering that the problem is a part of a homework in MC simulations and RNG testing with students having almost no experience in combinatorics, this seems like a really advanced problem, but I'll try to figure it out. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @darjacv $L \leq N$ is all that is relevant here.  I am unfamiliar with the phrases "MC simulations" or "RNG testing".  However, these phrases suggest that the assignment is either to correctly create a computer program to brute force compute the answer for a specific $L$ and $N$, or to use a computer to simulate many random observations.  In that event, this is **not a math problem**.  Going forward with your future mathSE questions, it is not a good idea to withhold pertinent info when you present a question.

Comment: I'm sorry I had to  abbreviate some words doe to character count (MC simulations are Monte Carlo simulations, and RNG testing is testing random number generators). The problem has two independent "parts", the second part is the coding part (simulation) which I know how to do because it doesn't require mathematical expressions, but the first part is actually my question, which is a math problem: to derive the exact analytical expression for the probability of ascending L sequence occurring in a series of N randomly generated numbers. I don't think I withheld any info relevant to the question.

Comment: @darjacv "Considering that the problem is a part of a homework in MC simulations and RNG testing with students having almost no experience in combinatorics," : this implies that the problem composer / problem assigner never intended that you attempt to attack the problem analytically.  What you are doing is therefore not a good idea.  That is, you are trying to attack a complicated analytical problem without adequate math training, such as spending a year on Combinatorics problems.  Jumping into the deep end of a pool, before you know how to swim is one thing, jumping into the ocean is another

Comment: Unfortunately,without going into irrelevant detail,I don't know how the composer intended the question to be tackled,on one hand it explicitly states to find the expression for the probability in question, on the other that doesn't seem right considering no comb. background or adequate literature/explanation for helping in such a quest.With that in mind,I asked a question here without making any assumptions of it's difficulty,just hoping for some clarity in any form-I thank you for your help because it confirmed my suspicion that it's too advanced of a problem with the conditions it came from.